# Что будет являться простым или составным сказуемым?

Tags: синтаксис

Начнем,  например,  с пирога – **пусть   это будет пирог с тмином**,  потому что совершенно все равно как то,  с чего начать,  так и то,  с чем пирог.

Что будет являться простым или составным сказуемым в выделенной части?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "это" - подлежащее, а "пусть будет пирог" (точнее "пусть будет пирог с тмином") - сказумое составное именное